# Macs not connecting with Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac

I have about 4 or 5 PowerMacs and iMacs that are not connecting to our 2008 Server R2.  The firewall is disabled on the server.  Is there a service that has to be running in order for them to find the server?  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Come on dude, you can do better than this - details, details, DETAILS please! what version/s of OSX are you using, what type of connection, what protocols etc. Throw us a bone! :)

Comment: I'll add an addendum to Chopper's comment ... were the workstations ever connecting before or is this initial configuration?

Comment: My apologies i should have given more info!  This is a client of mine and they have everything from Tiger to Snow Leopard.  The Macs could connect a while back (a month ago?), but for some reason they are not connecting now.  They are all wired and can get out to the internet, which means they can resolve DNS from the server, but cannot access the server on a file level.

Comment: Ok so it appears that SFM is no longer included in Server 2008 and is the reason the Macs cannot find the Windows Server.  Are there any 3rd party options out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Lion has solved this issue